# Copy war-file to remote server with pscp

Tags: deployment, maven-3, pscp

I'm using Maven 3 and I want to copy the war-file after it was built to a remote destination. I'm on a WinXP-machine and have PuTTY with its tools installed, i.e. pscp.exe exists.

I read about [maven-deploy-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html), but that only seems to apply to sending something into a repository. The remote site has a Tomcat running and hasn't got anything to do with a repository. It should only run the web-app.

For a while I was using maven-resources-plugin to copy the war-file to a local destination, but that doesn't seem to be able to send something to a remote site.

Can anyone please tell me what I can do? Maybe with a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting an entire day and trying various things like the ant-plugin and a wagon-thing I used the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/). I simply call `pscp.exe` the plain ol' style.

Obviously it doesn't use any of the "fancy" stuff, but it works.